# Repeat if statement 12 times

Tags: php, if-statement

Is there a simple way to repeat an `if` query 12 times on ascending numbers. My query is

```
<?php 
global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_music_file_url', true );
if (!empty($text)) {  ?>
<div class="row audiostyle" style="margin-top:45px;">
  <h3 class="col-md-1">1</h3>
  <h3 class="col-md-6"><?php global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_music_title', true ); echo $text; ?> </h3>
  <h3 class="col-md-3" style="font-size:1em;"><a href="<?php global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_buy_url', true ); echo $text; ?>" class="singlebutton" style="margin:0;">Buy Track</a></h3>
  <h3 class="col-md-2"><audio class="audio-player"src="<?php global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_music_file_url', true ); echo $text; ?> " width="100%" preload="none"></audio> </h3> 
</div>
```

And for each variable I have the ascending number next to it. For example the next if statement is

```
<?php } global $post; $text2 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_music_file_url2', true );
if (!empty($text2)) {  ?>
<div class="row audiostyle">
  <h3 class="col-md-1">2</h3>
  <h3 class="col-md-6"><?php global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_music_title2', true ); echo $text; ?> </h3>
  <h3 class="col-md-3" style="font-size:1em;"><a href="<?php global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_buy_url2', true ); echo $text; ?>" class="singlebutton" style="margin:0;">Buy Track</a></h3>
  <h3 class="col-md-2"><audio class="audio-player"src="<?php global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_music_file_url2', true ); echo $text; ?> " width="100%" preload="none"></audio> </h3>
</div>
```

Right now it works but there must be a simple way to write this to reduce the code. It runs from `test` to `test 12`.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Have you heared of looping statements.?

Comment: You can use variables in your variable name, for example: `${'text'.$variable}`. If $variable==2 then your variable name is $text2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++)
{
    if ($i > 1)
    {
        $file_url = '_cmb_music_file_url' . $i;
        $title = '_cmb_music_title' . $i;
        $buy_url = '_cmb_buy_url' . $i;
    }
    else
    {
        $file_url = '_cmb_music_file_url';
        $title = '_cmb_music_title';
        $buy_url = '_cmb_buy_url';
    }

   global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $file_url, true );

   if (!empty($text)) {
?>
    <div class="row audiostyle" style="margin-top:45px;">
        <h3 class="col-md-1">1</h3>
        <h3 class="col-md-6"><?php global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $title, true ); echo $text; ?> </h3>
        <h3 class="col-md-3" style="font-size:1em;"><a href="<?php global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $buy_url, true ); echo $text; ?>" class="singlebutton" style="margin:0;">Buy Track</a></h3>
        <h3 class="col-md-2"><audio class="audio-player"src="<?php global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $file_url, true ); echo $text; ?> " width="100%" preload="none"></audio> </h3> 
    </div>
<? }
}
```

Something like this might work.

Comment: This method worked best for me. Thanks to everyone who helped

Answer (score 1):

Use It

```
<?php 
global $post; 
$text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_music_file_url', true );
if (!empty($text)) {  ?>
<div class="row audiostyle" style="margin-top:45px;">
        <h3 class="col-md-1">1</h3>
        <h3 class="col-md-6"><?php global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_music_title', true ); echo $text; ?> </h3>
        <h3 class="col-md-3" style="font-size:1em;"><a href="<?php global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_buy_url', true ); echo $text; ?>" class="singlebutton" style="margin:0;">Buy Track</a></h3>
        <h3 class="col-md-2"><audio class="audio-player"src="<?php global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_music_file_url', true ); echo $text; ?> " width="100%" preload="none"></audio> </h3> 
</div>
<?php
}
for($i=2; $i<13; $i++){
$text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_music_file_url'.$i, true );
if (!empty($text)) {  ?>
<div class="row audiostyle" style="margin-top:45px;">
        <h3 class="col-md-1"><?php echo $i; ?></h3>
        <h3 class="col-md-6"><?php global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_music_title'.$i, true ); echo $text; ?> </h3>
        <h3 class="col-md-3" style="font-size:1em;"><a href="<?php global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_buy_url'.$i, true ); echo $text; ?>" class="singlebutton" style="margin:0;">Buy Track</a></h3>
        <h3 class="col-md-2"><audio class="audio-player"src="<?php global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_music_file_url'.$i, true ); echo $text; ?> " width="100%" preload="none"></audio> </h3> 
</div>
<?php 
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve like this by using [range()](http://php.net/range) function in php .

```
<?php
global $post;

foreach (range(1, 12) as $count) {
    $count = ($count == 1) ? '' : $count;
    $text = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_music_file_url' . $count, true);
    if (!empty($text)) {
        ?>
        <div class="row audiostyle" style="margin-top:45px;">
            <h3 class="col-md-1">1</h3>
            <h3 class="col-md-6">
                <?php
                $text = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_music_title' . $count, true);
                echo $text;
                ?> 
            </h3>
            <h3 class="col-md-3" style="font-size:1em;">
                <a href="<?php
                $text1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_buy_url' . $count, true);
                echo $text1;
                ?>" class="singlebutton" style="margin:0;">Buy Track</a>
            </h3>
            <h3 class="col-md-2">
                <audio class="audio-player"src="<?php
                       $text2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_music_file_url' . $count, true);
                       echo $text2;
                       ?> " width="100%" preload="none"></audio> 
            </h3> 
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your 12 variables in an array like this:

```
$tests = array($test, $test2, ...);
```

and then write a `foreach` statement:

```php
<?php 
foreach($tests as $text) {
    if (!empty($text)) {  ?>
    <div class="row audiostyle" style="margin-top:45px;">
        <h3 class="col-md-1">1</h3>
        <h3 class="col-md-6"><?php global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_music_title', true ); echo $text; ?> </h3>
        <h3 class="col-md-3" style="font-size:1em;"><a href="<?php global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_buy_url', true ); echo $text; ?>" class="singlebutton" style="margin:0;">Buy Track</a></h3>
        <h3 class="col-md-2"><audio class="audio-player"src="<?php global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_music_file_url', true ); echo $text; ?> " width="100%" preload="none"></audio> </h3> 
    </div>
    <?php
    } 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the names of the inputs you can use an array:

Instead of

```
<input name="_cmb_music_file_url1">
<input name="_cmb_music_file_url2">
<input name="_cmb_music_file_url3">
```

You can use

```
<input name="_cmb_music_file_url[1]">
<input name="_cmb_music_file_url[2]">
<input name="_cmb_music_file_url[3]">
```

Then in your code you can loop through it as an array.

Answer (score 0):

There are basicly 3 looping methods you can consider (and many more that I left out for the sake of simplicity):

`while()` will repeat unless you set a condition to make it stop,

`foreach()` will repeat  once for every element of an array, and

`for()` will repeat a given number of times.

I suggest that you get comfortable with each of them. `for` might have the most pitfalls, but fits best for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer. You must concatenate an increment variable with your text variable as follows.

```
    <?php for($i=1, $i<=12, $i++){

    global $post; $text.$i = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_music_file_url'.$i, true );
if (!empty($text.$i)) {  ?>
<div class="row audiostyle" style="margin-top:45px;">
  <h3 class="col-md-1"><?php echo $i; ?></h3>
  <h3 class="col-md-6"><?php global $post; $text.$i = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_music_title'.$i, true ); echo $text; ?> </h3>
  <h3 class="col-md-3" style="font-size:1em;"><a href="<?php global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_buy_url'.$i, true ); echo $text; ?>" class="singlebutton" style="margin:0;">Buy Track</a></h3>
  <h3 class="col-md-2"><audio class="audio-player"src="<?php global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_music_file_url'.$i, true ); echo $text; ?> " width="100%" preload="none"></audio> </h3>
</div>

<?php 
} //End if (!empty($text))

} //End of Foor loop 
?>
```